# PowerCLI: Task Automation

Tags: powershell, scripting, vmware, powercli

I have a script that I want to make automatically run every Monday and Thursday each week. I was curious how if it is possible to do this on PowerCLI or if I would have to create a .bat to accomplish this goal. I did some searching and learned that this piece of code was necessary in my script at the top of the line:

```
add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core # <----------

$server = $args[0]
$date = get-date
new-snapshot -vm $server -name "Auto Created via Powershell" -description $date
get-snapshot -vm $server | sort -property created -desc | select -skip 6 | foreach-object{remove-snapshot $_ -confirm:$false}
```

What else would I need to get this code to run every Monday and Thursday?

Thanks!

EDIT: Where would I edit the task scheduler in order to allow this to run? I've provided an image of where I'm at (that and I'm also a visual person :P )

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just using the [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Schedule-a-task) of Windows to execute your script as:

```
powershell.exe -file yourscript.ps1
```

use powershell /? to kown more options

Comment: This could work, although we'd have to make sure the server we do it on has the vSphere PowerCLI on it, and I think we'd have to run it through a bat or cmd file. Would I be wrong here?

Comment: Vote++.  Doing exactly that, kicking of PowerShell via the windows scheduler.  Depending on how pedantic you are, you may want to ensure that the PowerCLI modules are programmatically loaded as part of your script, rather than relying on the PS profile being configured...

Comment: @Christian Where exactly would I have to add this in the task schedular (new to using the task schedular)? I updated the original post to show where I'm at.

Comment: In tab 'schedule' add when you want to start it based on your needs . From the image I can't see if is scheduled.

Comment: @Christian it is already scheduled for the days that I need. My question is more so where do I add "powershell.exe -file snapshot.ps1" in order to make the powershell script run rather than just open when it is scheduled.

Comment: @julian In run field... put full path as in this example `c:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file c:\script\yourscript.ps1`